# Stripe Recurring payments with In App Wallet

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a question that I'd like to hear your opinion how would you go about solving this.

The client has recurring monthly payment packages available, and he'd like to setup payment through the card or via wallet in app (if you have sufficient funds available)

So you can deposit $100 into the app once and subscribe to the package that costs eg. $50. 2 months it would subtract from the in app balance the third time once you don't have enough in there it would charge directly to the bank.

Do you have any idea how to handle this? I didn't find any webhooks triggering prior to subscription payment processing to decide whether to continue or stop?

Comment: When you say "You can deposit $100 into the app" where is that money actually being transferred to?  Where does it get debited from when each monthly subscription is processed?

Comment: User pays from his credit card into our account. And we give him in app balance that is used to pay monthly subscriptions. But if there is no balance within the app then we should charge him directly

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment response, I suspect your best bet is to use a [webhook endpoint](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks).

I would be listening to the events around `payment_intent` and `invoice` objects.  Then, on your server, you keep track of whether they have a remaining balance *after* each transaction and configure their next subscription charge based on whether they have another $50 in their account or not.